# iOS Universal Application: the Minimum OS Version is Different than the Deployment Target

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I'm developing a universal iOS application and I set the deployment target to any version before 3.2. However, when it is compiled and I go to install it on an older device, xcode won't install it because version 3.2 is being required. The info.plist generated confirms that the minimum os version is being set 3.2. Why is this?

I have also weak-linked all of the frameworks. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in XCode that may not have been fixed yet: You need to do all the project settings BOTH for the current target (select target and hit cmd + i) and in the project settings (project > edit project settings). The two forms are absolutely identical and hold the same information, however they do not correspond to each other - changes made in one form wouldn't reflect in the other. So, make sure to fill in the necessary information in both places and also make sure you're using the same configuration (debug, release,..) for each form.
Maybe so far the target OS information has been read just from one form - the one you didn't fill in.

Comment: You can try deleting the value from the target setting entirely; it should then inherit from the project.  Why doesn't Xcode do that in the first place?  WHO KNOWS.

Comment: Your comment saved me a lot of hours of pain !, thank You Toastor.

Comment: Thanks for this! See my answer below for how this helped me in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7, I got error `module file's minimum target is ios8.2` while building my unit tests after changing my main target's Deployment Target from 8.1 to 8.2.

Thanks to @Toastor's answer (from 5 years ago!) I was able to solve the error by also changing my **project's** Deployment Target from 8.1 to 8.2.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You should probably set the deployment target to 3.2 to match your device. The "Base SDK" should be set to a lower version like 3.1.3 for example.

Comment: The base SDK should always be set to the HIGHEST version - it is the one you build against, and means any new features can be included.